# Is there any option to Display the galleria gallery inside the fancybox?

Tags: jquery, fancybox, galleria

I am using the fancybox.I want to display the image gallery using the galleria plugin inside the fancy box similar to [this](http://www.realestate.com.au/property-house-nsw-chatswood-110664113)

```
jQuery(".pika-stage img").live('click',function(){
            var product_id = <?php echo $Product->id;?>;
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: "<?php echo $currenturl;?>",
                type: "POST",
                data:{tasksubmit:"enlarge",productid:product_id},
                success: function(data){
                    var gal_img ='<div id= gallery>'+data+'</div>';
                    jQuery.fancybox({
                        'content': gal_img
                     });
                   }

                })
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got the solution for displaying the gallery inside the light box. I am using  the Pretty photo plugin for displaying the gallery in the light box. [Demo for Preety Photo](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/)